# Change the text "Billing address" for a specific product category in order received and order email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Inspired by: [Change Checkout “Billing Details” text for a specific product in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55389458/change-checkout-billing-details-text-for-a-specific-product-in-woocommerce) I need to modify the following code to change the texts based on a specific product category. In **Checkout Page** the text would change from: "Billing details" to: "Receipt details" in **Order Received** and **Order Email** the text would change from: Billing address "to:" Receipt details " `

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'change_conditionally_checkout_heading_text', 10, 3 );
function change_conditionally_checkout_heading_text( $translated, $text, $domain  ) {
    if( $text === 'Billing details' && is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ){
        // HERE set the desired specific product ID
        $targeted_product_id = 1980;

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if( $targeted_product_id == $cart_item['data']->get_id() ) {
                return __( 'Receipt details', $domain );
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
        }
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

`

My knowledge in php is basic, please I appreciate very much in what you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the text "Billing address" with "Receipt details" in the email-addresses.php.

Note: Is not a good idea to update the core files because after the plugin updates your changes will be overwritten.

Go to **wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/emails/email-addresses.php** and copy the file to your child theme folder **wp-content/themes/your-theme/woocommerce/emails/**. Put the file and find and replace the text "Billing address" with "Receipt details"

Comment: thanks for your answer but what I need is that the text is changed according to a product category automatically when the customer makes the purchase of a product that belongs to that category. The current code works fine changing the Billing Details text to Receipt Details but it only works on the checkoutpage, on the rest of the pages and the email does not make the change.

Comment: The code above I provided is for the email not on the checkout page. Take a look at this https://www.tychesoftwares.com/how-to-customize-woocommerce-order-emails/

Comment: If I change the text as you indicate it will remain permanent, and what I need is that the text is changed automatically and only for a specific product category.

The original text is: Billing Details.

The text must change for a specific product category to: Receipt Details.

This change must appear everywhere, that is: on the checkout page, order received, and email order. Thanks for listening to my question.

Comment: The code I post works great on the checkout page.

When I purchase the product that is within Category ID: 1980, the Billing Details text automatically changes on the payment page to Receipt Details.

I need this text to also change to Receipt Details on the order received page and the order email.

Comment: You can check the **email-addresses.php**. I managed to change the "Billing address" based on product id. I added for checking the category id but I have not tested it but you got the idea.

`$cstm_text_info = "Billing address";
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
 $cstm_product_id = $item->get_product_id(); 
 if($cstm_product_id == 4459) {
  $cstm_text_info = "Receipt details";
 }
}`

`$terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
  $cat_id = $term->id;
  if($cat_id == 1980) {
  $cstm_text_info = "Receipt details";
 }
}`

Comment: in the File fuctions.php ?

Comment: No, you can't do that in functions.php. You need custom modification on this please refer to my first answer. From there you can add a condition statement based on the product category and change dynamically the "Billing address" label

Comment: Thanks but my knowledge in php is basic, I would not know how to do it.